# Python xml parsing using minidom

Tags: python, xml, parsing

I just started learning how to parse xml using `minidom`. I tried to get the author's names (xml data is down below) using the following code:

```
from xml.dom import minidom

xmldoc = minidom.parse("cora.xml")

author = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName ('author')

for author in author:
    authorID=author.getElementsByTagName('author id')
    print authorID
```

I got empty brackets(`[]`) all the way. Can someone please help me out? I will also need the      title and venue. Thanks in advance. See xml data below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<coraRADD>
   <publication id="ahlskog1994a">
      <author id="199">M. Ahlskog</author>
      <author id="74"> J. Paloheimo</author>
      <author id="64"> H. Stubb</author>
      <author id="103"> P. Dyreklev</author>
      <author id="54"> M. Fahlman</author>
      <title>Inganas</title>
      <title>and</title>
      <title>M.R.</title>
      <venue>
         <venue pubid="ahlskog1994a" id="1">
                  <name>Andersson</name>
                  <name> J Appl. Phys.</name>
                  <vol>76</vol>
                  <date> (1994). </date>
            </venue>
```

Comment: Is that the correct XML data? There’s an extra opening `<venue>` tag, and the `<publication>` and `<coraRADD>` tags aren’t closed.

Comment: Hi Paul, that's the correct XML data. I copied it directly from the XML file.

Comment: Are you married to the minidom library? The ElementTree API is much easier to use, for example.

Comment: I just started parsing, hence I do not know much about the other API's. I'll try ElementTree if its really that much easier to use. Thanks.

Comment: When I save that XML to my computer and attempt to parse it using minidom (`xmldoc = minidom.parse("cora.xml")`), I get an `xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError` error. Maybe I should say “is that the complete XML data”?

Comment: Hi Paul, the XML data is just too large, but here is just a bit of how it looks like:

Answer (score 1):

You can only find tags with `getElementsByTagName()`, not attributes. You'll need to access those through the [`Element.getAttribute()` method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.dom.html#xml.dom.Element.getAttribute) instead:

```
for author in author:
    authorID = author.getAttribute('id')
    print authorID
```

If you are still learning about parsing XML, you really want to stay away from the DOM. The DOM API is overly verbose to fit many different programming languages.

The [ElementTree API](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) would be easier to use:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('cora.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

# loop over all publications
for pub in root.findall('publication'):
    print ' '.join([t.text for t in pub.findall('title')])
    for author in pub.findall('author'):
        print 'Author id: {}'.format(author.attrib['id'])
        print 'Author name: {}'.format(author.text)
    for venue in pub.findall('.//venue[@id]'):  # all venue tags with id attribute
        print ', '.join([name.text for name in venue.findall('name')])
```

Comment: Hi Pieters, its working now. Thanks alot, but I am more interested in the names of the authors, and the venue. Any ideas?

Comment: @user2274879: Loop over the publications instead then (`for pub in root.findall('publication'):`) then find authors from there (`for author in pub.findall('author')`) and venues (`for venue in pub.findall('.//venue[@id]')` perhaps, to find just those with an `id` attribute). Author names are text content in the tag, so `author.text` will get you that.

Comment: I got the following error when i tried using author.tex: TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Comment: @user2274879: No `()`; `.text` is an attribute (and yes, I made that mistake at first, corrected since).

Comment: Hi Pieters, its working like magic. I was actually fraustrated before posting the question.

Comment: Thank you very much Pieters. I've got more unanswered questions, but not today. Thanks and take care.